# about a small program

Tags: scheme, racket

Consider the following program. It's supposed to take a list of strings, and return a string whose characters are the first character from each string.  For instance, `(downward (cons "caa" (cons "abbb" empty))` should return `"ca"`.  Why do I keep getting an error?

```
(define (downward l)
  (cond
    [(empty? l) ""]
    [else (substring (first l) 0 1
            (downward (rest l)))]))
```

Comment: I see that there's an accepted answer, but can you include the actual error that you're getting.  It may help users in the future find the question, and it will help people reading the answer know what the actual problem was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correctly iterating over the input, but forgot to "stick together" each part of the output. In this case, `string-append` will allow you to put together all the elements of the answer:

```
(define (downward l)
  (cond
    [(empty? l) ""]
    [else (string-append (substring (first l) 0 1)
                         (downward (rest l)))]))
```

This is how it works:

```
(downward '("caa" "abbb"))
=> "ca"
```

On second thought, the question is a bit ambiguous. Do you want a *string* as the output? or a *list*? If it's a list, you only have to change the base case and the "sticking" procedure - use `cons` for building lists, in the same way that `string-append` is useful for building strings:

```
(define (downward l)
  (cond
    [(empty? l) empty]
    [else (cons (substring (first l) 0 1)
                (downward (rest l)))]))


(downward '("caa" "abbb"))
=> '("c" "a")
```